# IsChanged( ) is not working as expected

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I got a requirement to restrict record ownership changes of Leads to the Users except some Users. So, I wrote a validation rule like this. But, it is restricting all the users.

Please let me know where I missed the use case.

Validation rule:

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED( OwnerId ),
  OR(
    $Profile.Name <> 'LRS Member',
    $Profile.Name <> 'Research Team',
    $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
    $Profile.Name <> 'Sales Manager No IP restriction'
  ) 
)\
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your OR statement will always evaluate to True. You should remove the OR statement and re-write your validation rule as follows:

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED( OwnerId ),
    $Profile.Name <> 'LRS Member',
    $Profile.Name <> 'Research Team',
    $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
    $Profile.Name <> 'Sales Manager No IP restriction'
)
```

Comment: Just now i did the same it's working like charm.@Jason Walke

Comment: @Pavantej - If answer solved your problem lease mark as accepted so others with similar question can find answers